# Solving $[x]+[x]=[2x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

> Solving the equation $[x]+[x]=[2x]$

Since $[x]$ is the greatest integer function.

I tried, $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $[x]=x$ and $[2x]=2x$ this implies that $[x]+[x]=[2x]$, but if $x=a+k$, with $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq k<\frac12$ then $[x]=x$ and $[2x]=2x$ this too implies that $[x]+[x]=[2x]$.
There is another possibility for $x$? Is this correct? And most importantly, how to write this post, or just okay?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: $x=0$ also fits in.

Comment: when $x=a+k$ isn't $[x]=a$ ?

Comment: Yes, but the point is equality doesn't hold for $k\ge \frac12$ @Shubham

Comment: Use the notation $\large\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have: $[2x]=[x]+[x+\frac{1}{2}]$ We replace it in the equation: $2[x]=[x]+[x+\frac{1}{2}]$ so $[x]=[x+\frac{1}{2}]$ which means $x-[x]<\frac{1}{2}$ so the solution set is: $x=n+k$ where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $k<\frac{1}{2}$

And:

> There is another possibility for x?

No.

> Is this correct?

Yes

> how to write this post, or just okay?

I don't understand what you mean by this.